# Settings.txt with connection string gets removed after publish into Azure

Tags: azure, sql-server-ce, azure-web-app-service, nopcommerce

I published my NopCommerce application to azure. as you may know connection string is defined in the settings.txt file under the app_data. It is also published with all files but strange thing is that when I open the settings.txt file. connections string is removed.

It should look like this

- DataProvider: SQL Server CE
- DataConnectionString: `Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Nop.Db.sdf;Persist Security Info=False`

but published version looks like that

- DataProvider:
- DataConnectionString:

Any idea why is that happening? or is there another way to copy directly? I am new on Azure and I couldn't find published files even.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can see the file system and edit \ upload files by using the SCM endpoint, there is good information in this blog: http://blogs.staykov.net/2013/12/windows-azure-secrets-of-web-site.html 
Basically you take the url for your site `http://<your_site>.azurewebsites.net` and add scm to the url so it will be: `http://<your_site>.scm.azurewebsites.net`. Browsing to this location will give you access to a file browser as well as a set of diagnostics tools.

Comment: this really did the job. I could update the settings.txt but copy pasting the text inside but is it possible to upload a file directly using this?

Comment: @batmaci You can drag and drop a file to the DebugConsole's file explorer to upload it (at `http://<yoursite>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`